# My website blog section has been replaced with adult blog posts

Tags: blog, hacked

I encountered a problem in the Blog section. All of my existing blog posts have been replaced with some adult blog articles. I checked for malware but there is no malware as well. If anyone is familiar with this or knows this. Can you advise me on this? Post author also shows as the current registered user.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there's no malware, check your site's settings if **Anyone can register** is on and the **New user default role** is set to something other than Subscriber.

Comment: Your website has likely been hacked. You should start with the official FAQ and go from there: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/

Comment: @Abhik no one can register. And the default user role is Subscriber.